# Cannot resolve package source for PSGallery. What is OneGetTestSource PSRepository?

Tags: powershell

What is going on with PSGallery and OneGetTestSource? It appears that PSGallery is no longer available. Is OneGetTestSource a legitimate source for modules? Should I install from there?

```
PS C:\> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
Tls12
PS C:\> Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
OneGetTestSource          Trusted              https://www.poshtestgallery.com/api/v2/
PSGallery                 Trusted              https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
LocalRepo                 Trusted              C:\src\Repo

PS C:\> Get-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Management

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-Item, Clear-ItemProperty…}

PS C:\> Get-InstalledModule -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Get-Package: C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules\PowerShellGet\PSModule.psm1:9445
Line |
9445 |          PackageManagement\Get-Package @PSBoundParameters | Microsoft. …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Management'.

PS C:\> Find-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'.
Find-Package: C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules\PowerShellGet\PSModule.psm1:8879
Line |
8879 |          PackageManagement\Find-Package @PSBoundParameters | Microsoft …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Management'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module
     | repositories.

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.1.4
PS C:\> Find-Module -Name az
WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'.

Version              Name                                Repository           Description
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------
6.3.0                Az                                  OneGetTestSource     Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Cmdlets to manage resources in Azure. This module is compatible with PowerSh…
```

**Update 2021-08-20 11:29 CDT**

Access to PSGallery appears to be working. But, the question remains about OneGetTestSource. Is this a trustworthy PSRepository?

```
PS C:\> get-module -Name PSReadLine

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Script     2.1.0                 PSReadLine                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, ...
```

Comment: Can you please `Unregister-PSRepository PSGallery` and try to register with default and check once. You can use this command to do so. `Register-PSRepository -default`

Comment: @RanadipDutta, the problem no longer occurs. The question remains about OneGetTestSource.

Comment: You have probably at some point ran (an earlier version of) the PowerShell test suite as [seen here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/dc0eff210e4582f15bdd57accb9ea764a45e0ef4/test/powershell/Modules/PackageManagement/PackageManagement.Tests.ps1#L16-L17).